# Typescript definitions with NODE_PATH

Tags: typescript

I've a project in TS which uses `NODE_PATH` for path resolution.

Let's suppose we're working in folder: `/Users/ndeitch/git/some-project`

And We've a `Domain` class:

path: `/Users/ndeitch/git/some-project/src/domain/domain.ts`

```js
export class Service {
  constructor(name: string) {}
}
```

And a `Service` class:

path: `/Users/ndeitch/git/some-project/src/service/service.ts`

```js
import { Domain } from 'src/domain/domain.ts'

export abstract class Service {
  create(domain: Domain): Promise<Domain>
}
```

And this code runs with with the following command:

path: `/Users/ndeitch/git/some-project`

I'm using `Nest` but I think it's not relevant

`NODE_PATH=. nest start`

It works fine.

The problem is when I publish this as npm package.

The generated service code has a `src/domain` import which is not resolved and I lost intellisense from VSCode.

My tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declarationMap": true
  }
}
```

Any idea on how can I resolve this?

PS: I've no problem coding this lib, the only problem is when a install it and check types, all types become `any` type

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be a known issue, check this thread: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26722#issuecomment-421095210

Comment: I ended it up refactoring project imports